# How to send flutter push notification to specific user? - Flutter Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification for users who have made certain operations in my application. So I just want to send notifications to certain people, the options to send to a certain community already exist in firebase. I personally want to send notifications to some users. Is there a specific way or method for this?

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging has no concept of a user. You'll want to track the FCM tokens for the device(s) that a user is active on, and then send to those tokens. This cannot be done from within your Flutter app directly, as that would be a security risk. Instead you'll need to do this from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.